Pressure washing advice with shoddy siding?
My house has vinyl siding and I don't think it was installed very well.  The seam where pieces mate have visible gaps and I have no faith that whomever did siding knew what they were doing.
Aside from that, the house looks dirty.  We thought of having someone pressure wash it but are fearful about water getting behind the siding.  Advice?  How should we vet our workers?

Bucket of soapy water, long-handled scrub brush, and a normal hose to rinse. Or: New siding/fix the installed siding (which depending how hopeless the present install is, or perhaps how hard the dirt is to get off, or how much you'd like a different color.)

I'm not a fan of pressure washing anything. It forces water into places it should not be. Using pressure on a poor siding job is a recipe for disaster.  Fix the siding issue then wash as Ecnerwal suggested, with a long handled boat or MH brush soapy water and a hose.

You know that siding is not 'nailed' to but hung on the walls and the edges are overlapped to allow expansion and contraction...right?

@SteveWellens yes I know that.  This looks particularly sloppy
